# Flexbox or CSS Grid: How to let one column be larger than two others?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

How would you solve this Layout if you have only 3 Containers:

```
<div class="main-container">
 <div class="blue-container"></div>
 <div class="red-container"></div>
 <div class="green-container"></div>
</div>

.main-container {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: stretch;
 align-content: stretch;
}

.blue-container, .red-container {
 width: 50%;
}  

.green-container {
 flex-basis: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
```

I solved it for Desktop (code above) and Mobile (everything flex-basis: 100%). But how to solve the tablet layout without adding more Markup/`<div>`'s?

[image: three column layout example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grid solution. Look how compact and nice it is. For all tree conditions. Used [grid-template-areas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas). Try it while resizing the viewport.

```css
.main-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "blue red"
    "green green";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: auto; 
  grid-gap: 10px;
  min-height: 150px; /*just for instance */
}

.blue-container {
  grid-area: blue;
  background: blue;
}

.red-container {
  grid-area: red;
  background: red;
}  

.green-container {
  grid-area: green;
  background: green;
}

/* tablet */
@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .main-container {
    grid-template-areas:
      "blue red"
      "green red";
  }
}

/* mobile */
@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  .main-container {
    grid-template-areas:
      "blue blue"
      "red red"
      "green green";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
 <div class="blue-container"></div>
 <div class="red-container"></div>
 <div class="green-container"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `flex-direction` to column and use the `order` property. `Flex-basis` will determine the height:

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  height: 100vh;
}

.red-container {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  background: red;
  order: 3;
}

.green-container {
  background: green;
  order: 2;
  flex-basis: 25%;
}

.blue-container {
  background: blue;
  order: 1;
  flex-basis: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="blue-container"></div>
  <div class="red-container"></div>
  <div class="green-container"></div>
</div>
```